# sql server performance issue during import

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am importing (transferring) records from one server to another server in sql server: TABLE A (SERVER 1) -> TABLE B (SERVER 2). Total no of records in Table A is 2 million. It is sometimes too slow.

is there any scripts to clear or shrink transaction logs?.

transaction log will impact the performance?

Comment: Provide details in your question about how you are transferring data. A common approach for copying large amounts of data is with a bulk insert method in batches to keep transaction log size reasonable along with minimally logging techniques if possible. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421.aspx.

Comment: Guessing "more time" means somehow too long. Please be specific with your question. We can't know what your situation is, and what is acceptable for you.

Comment: We care using one application.This application was developed by asp.net.Using this application we are inserting records from one server to another server.for example it is taking 8 hour for inserting 11 lakshs records means next time it is taking more time for insertion.This process  will continue for one week time.So our client asking scripts to improve performance.Is there any scripts to clear or shirnk the log files.

Comment: whether we have to use dbcc shrink file command? or we have to use rebuild an index? for improving performance.Please give some idea.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET SqlClient includes a [`SqlBulkCopy` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy) to provide SQL Server bulk insert functionality. `SqlBulkCopy` is orders of magnitude faster than individual `INSERT` statements. I expect SqlBulkCopy will copy 1 million rows in well under a minute.

A common practice with large bulk inserts is to perform the task in smaller batches to reduce transaction log space requirements.

Comment: ok.But we are not able to change that code at present.so shall we use dbcc shrink file command or rebuild an index to improve performance?.any other way to improve performance(any sql scripts)?

Comment: dbc_shrink file is right approach?or rebuild index is right approach?

Comment: shall i use this command?
USE [TestFileShrink]
‌GO
‌DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'TestFileShrink_data', 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
‌GO
‌or shall i use index rebuild command?

Comment: `SHINKFILE` may worsen performance because in introduces fragmentation. Updating stats or rebuilding indexes may help query performance but probably not inserts. I doubt you can do much to improve performance unilaterally in the SQL Side to address a flawed application design.